# Proper way to bottom align text of different font sizes in adjacent blocks?

Tags: html, css

I have text in adjacent blocks where the font sizes are different, but I want the text in both to be bottom aligned with each other. More specifically, I want the `section` vertically centered within the `header`, but I want the text within `h1` and `nav` to have their bottom edge aligned. I can tweak margins or absolute positioning to get the second block's text aligned with the first, but the alignment breaks as soon as I zoom the page. I have a [codepen](http://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/WbxPMW?editors=110), and here's the code:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <section>
    <h1>SITENAME</h1>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header { width:100%; background-color:#ddd; }

header section {
  width:80%;
  max-width:980px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

header section h1, header section nav { 
  margin:20px 0 20px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}

header section h1 { font-size:2em; }

header section nav { 
  position:absolute; 
  right:0; 
  text-align:right; 
}

nav ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
nav li { display:inline; }
nav li a { margin-left:2em; text-decoration:none; }
body { margin:0; font-family:sans-serif; }
```

Ideas? Seems like this must be a common need but I'm not finding it.

Comment: wouldn't you want all of them(h1 and links) to be in the center(vertically) of the section?

Comment: I want the `section` vertically centered within the `header`, but I want the text within `h1` and `nav` to have their bottom edge aligned.

Comment: @mix decide what you want. The requests (if you're picky about px-perfect) are not the same.

Comment: use line-height to move text exactly in centre of section `header section h1, header section nav 
{ 
  margin:20px 0 20px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
}`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I'm not sure what you're saying (I'm not trying to be contradictory). I want the `section` vertically centered (its height being determined by the largest of the two elements it contains---in my case the `h1`), and then I want the text in both to appear bottom aligned (so that the text in the smallest height element is aligned with the largest one).

@AdityaShedge I tried line-height, but that aligns the text along their vertical centers, not their vertical bottom.

Comment: You should describe *in the question* itself (not just as discussion comments) what you want. Align exactly what to what how?

Answer (score 2):

If you put **both** `h1` and `<nav>` to be `display:inline-block` you'll get along the default `vertical-align: baseline;` (by default) which will align the texts of your elements exactly as you need them: http://jsbin.com/zohupu/1/edit?html,css,output

*Otherwise* if you set an element to `position:absolute` you remove it from it's natural flow and all you can do is approximate:

```
header section nav { 
  position:absolute; 
  right:0; 
  line-height:3.1em;      /* added */
  /*text-align:right;   not needed */
}
```

Comment: Nice. 3.15em seems a little more precise, but it does the job well at normal zoom. At least in Chrome, however, it fails at some zoom levels. Perhaps tolerable, but not ideal. In this codepen I've set the width too narrow so you can easily see the alignment http://codepen.io/bengrosser/pen/raLRaj

Comment: @mix Yes, 3.15 is just a *best fit* cause you cannot set to position:absolute and expect it to follow the natural alignments cause being *out of flow*. In [this demo](http://jsbin.com/zohupu/1/edit?html,css,output) you can see an example where position:absolute is not used, instead the elements are set to `inline-block` with the default [vertical-align:baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) they follow the correct alignment directive which is what you're striving to achieve (which would probably best fit my answer, but not sure if your exact requirements)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I do want the `nav` flush against the right edge of `header`, which is why I'm using `absolute`. I can get it over there using `inline-block` by setting widths on the `h1` and `nav` and setting `text-align:right` on `nav`, but then the layout breaks at smaller zoom sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Using css transform will help.
Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/claytonF/34wcu10e/1/

```css
header {
  width:100%;
  background-color:#ddd;
}

header section {
  width:80%;
  max-width:680px;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
}

header section h1, header section nav 
{ 
  margin:20px 0 20px 0;
  display:inline-block;
}
header section h1, header section nav, header section nav li a 
{
  height:2em;
}

header section h1 { 
  font-size:2em;
}

header section nav { 
  position:absolute; 
  right:0; 
  text-align:right;
  
}

nav ul { margin:0; padding:0;}
nav li { 
  display:block; 
  position:relative; 
  float:left; 
   
}
nav li a { 
  margin-left:2em;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  transform:translate(0%,50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(0%,50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(0%,50%);
  -o-transform:translate(0%,50%);
}

body { margin:0; font-family:sans-serif; }
```

```html
<header>
  <section>
    <h1>SITENAME</h1>
    <nav role="navigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">stuff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </section>
</header>
```

I did have to set a height for the H1, nav and nav li a elements. Don't know how to avoid that. I just set them to the height of the H1 text (2em).

Then set the nav li's to `display:block`and `float:left` then applied `transform:translate(0%,50%);`to the `nav li a` element.

Hope that helps.